# Authentication role - Clean Architecture

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, clean-architecture

Lately I have been facing a problem that I wasn't able to came out with a solution,  I am building an android application following the Clean Architecture and everything was going fine until I had to think about the authentication role.

I have this structure (layers) on my app: 
[ui](activities and fragments) -> [presentation](view models) -> [domain](use case) -> data -> [remote, cache, database].

Now, let's suppose that I want to log in into my app, first I'll go through the login screen and put users credentials, after that I'll call the LoginViewModel and then the LoginUseCase passing the email and password. In its turn, the use case will call the repository, let's say, authenticate and then I'll make a request to the backend with the credentials, if everything's ok then I'll receive back a token that I should store in some fashion, the problem start here, I've created a interceptor that is responsible to get the token from the header, but I have to save it and for that I need to access the shared preferences, is correct to have access to it inside my interceptor? And in every request I had to send it  to my backend, what's the best approach ?

I also saw this tutorial https://medium.com/@tsaha.cse/advanced-retrofit2-part-2-authorization-handling-ea1431cb86be but I think that it's not correct to have access to database inside your application class, am I wrong?

Thank you all for reading this, I'm struggling to find out the best approach, so any help are welcome.

Comment: Is it possible to get back new token from Retrofit's Response class? If yes, in repository module which is place to get Retrofit network result, we can save such token into cache module.

Answer (score 1):

it's not really related to `CleanArchitecture`. Here're answers for your questions:

1. I have to save it and for that I need to access the shared preferences, is correct to have access to it inside my interceptor?

-> Yes, you should save it to `SharedPreferences`, but you should not access `SharedPreferences` inside your `interceptor`. You should make your `interceptor` Singleton and create a new `setHeaderToken(String token)` function in your `interceptor`. After authorizing, you can set header token to your `interceptor`. Something like:

```
class MyInterceptor{
    String token = null;
    public void setHeaderToken(String token){
         //do set...
    };
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
         if(token == null) //do nothing
         else // do add header
    }
}

// add the singleton Interceptor to your OkHttp Client Builder and use it.
```

2. You should not connect Application class with your database directly. You should use a domain layer to do so instead.

Comment: Thank for your reply, but the question is how can I save the token into shared preferences if I can't have it inside the interceptor?

Comment: @Boni not sure what you mean. You should save token into shared preferences in your token API instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "in your token API", I'm sorry to disturb you with that but it's hard for me to figure out a way to solve it